# Multi Dimensional Array Calculation in php ( PHP Ranking not working )

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, output, ranking

> Hi guys,
> I have Result like this ,but Problem is this Result's Rank not correct , Please can you any one help for me, I have tried many times for many days now to get the result through this code but it was never successful so please help me, I have put all the codes below for you.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sturoll_no] => MAX001
            [stu_name] => Name01
            [stu_pres] => 70.00
            [rank] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sturoll_no] => MAX002
            [stu_name] => H.M.Dehan 
            [stu_pres] => 53.33
            [rank] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [sturoll_no] => MAX003
            [stu_name] => Chamudi 
            [stu_pres] => 30.00
            [rank] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [sturoll_no] => MAX004
            [stu_name] => D Laknara
            [stu_pres] => 71.67
            [rank] => 4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [sturoll_no] => MAX005
            [stu_name] => D M Imasha 
            [stu_pres] => 21.67
            [rank] => 5
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [sturoll_no] => Max006
            [stu_name] => Name05
            [stu_pres] => 63.33
            [rank] => 6
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [sturoll_no] => MAX007
            [stu_name] => Name06
            [stu_pr found es] => 66.67
            [rank] => 7
        )
```

> ```
> > i found this code : from https://www.techantena.com/4897/calculate-rank-array-values-php/
>
> > MY CODE LIKE THIS --->>>>
>
>
> $student_mark = [
>     [
>         'reg_no'       => 'REG_10001',
>         'student_name' => 'Rita Book',
>         'mark'         => '89',
>     ],[
>         'reg_no'       => 'REG_10002',
>         'student_name' => 'A. Mused',
>         'mark'         => '95',
>     ],[
>         'reg_no'       => 'REG_10003',
>         'student_name' => 'Rose Bush',
>         'mark'         => '35',
>     ],[
>         'reg_no'       => 'REG_10004',
>         'student_name' => 'Greg Arias',
>         'mark'         => '86',
>     ],[
>         'reg_no'       => 'REG_10005',
>         'student_name' => 'Skye Blue',
>         'mark'         => '12',
>     ],[
>         'reg_no'       => 'REG_10006',
>         'student_name' => 'Don Messwidme',
>         'mark'         => '0',
>     ],[
>         'reg_no'       => 'REG_10007',
>         'student_name' => 'Emma Grate',
>         'mark'         => '0',
>     ],[
>         'reg_no'       => 'REG_10008',
>         'student_name' => 'Sarah Moanees',
>         'mark'         => '75',
>     ],[
>         'reg_no'       => 'REG_10009',
>         'student_name' => 'Mal Nurrisht',
>         'mark'         => '86',
>     ],[
>         'reg_no'       => 'REG_10010',
>         'student_name' => 'Stanley Knife',
>         'mark'         => '35',
>     ],
> ];
>
> $student_rank = calculate_rank($student_mark);
>
> //calculate rank for multi dimensional array
> function calculate_rank($rank_values): array {
>     $rank = 0;
>     $r_last = null;
>     foreach ($rank_values as $key => $arr) {
>         if ($arr['mark'] != $r_last) {
>             if($arr['mark'] > 0){ //if you want to set zero rank for values zero
>                 $rank++;
>             }
>             $r_last = $arr['mark'];
>         }
>
>         $rank_values[$key]['rank'] = $arr['mark'] > 0 ? $rank: 0; //if you want to set zero rank for values zero
>     }
>     return $rank_values;
> }
> ```

> Can you anyone help for me i Was really stuck on this , Output ok but rank calculation is not correct
> I need the Total Solution for this Question

Comment: Please clarify the input and required output. The array keys in your examples don't match, is that just part of the example code?

Answer (score 0):

simply we need to sort this array by mark first, we can use [the custom sort function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort by `mark` key:

```php
usort($student_mark, function ($a, $b) {
    return $b['mark'] <=> $a['mark']; 
});
```

then just add the field rank to the array:

```php
foreach ($student_mark as $i => &$student) { // we used the pointer to directly add the rank key to the array
    $student['rank'] = $i+1;
}
```

Comment: Please can you add the Full code !

Comment: this is the full code , just add these two blocks instead of the function and it should do the work, it will update the array `$student_mark`, as we are using the pointer

Comment: Thank you for your kind help , Can you please re comment the your code with my code , it means full code , because i am not perfect person for php so I cannot identify the write point to Paster your code